# Open SQL FileStream with MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012, filestream

I have a database table that stores files using SQL FileStream.

I have enabled full file streaming capibilities in SQL Instance

I would like to produce a hyperlink that will allow me to open the file in an external application (Word, visio, excel)  and re-save it after making changes.  Is this possible with FileStream?

Currently this is the code i am using to view the document.  But this does not appear to be using the FileStream capibility.

```
public FileContentResult GetDoc(int id)
    {
        Document doc = db.Documents.Single(o => o.Id == id);



        byte[] fileContent = null;
        string mimeType = "";
        string filename = "";

        fileContent = (byte[])doc.DocumentContents;
        mimeType = doc.DocumentMimeType;
        filename = doc.DocumentFileName;

        return File(fileContent, mimeType, filename);

    }
```